# Using the article twice or once in "a more practical and a useful approach"?

Tags: indefinite-articles

> - In this regard, heating seems to be **a** more practical and useful approach.
> - In this regard, heating seems to be **a** more practical and **a** useful approach.

What is the general rule for use of *a/an/the* in these type of cases?

Comment: is this more ELL ?

Comment: This is definitely ELL, but I'm afraid migration makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on intent of the sentence. Let's say heating is being compared here to some unknown phenomenon X.

> If heating is both a *more practical* and a *more useful* approach than X, then leave off the 'a'.
>   The resultant sentence would be "In this regard, heating seems to be a more practical and useful approach."

However,

> If heating is a *more practical* approach as compared to X, but heating is *useful* as opposed to X which is *not useful*, then use the article 'a'.
>   The resultant sentence would be "In this regard, heating seems to be a more practical and a useful approach."

By leaving off the 'a', you're letting *more* modify both *practical and useful*. By keeping it you have two disjoint adjectives, *more practical* and *useful*.

Comment: OK to be more  specific, I am comparing heating with X, and heating appears to be more practical and also more useful than X.

Comment: @user88067 Leave off the 'a' then! :)

Comment: So which of the sentences is correct? Do i put two A's or only one A. Plz explain. Can you write the correct sentence also for easy understanding. Thanx

Comment: or I don't use any A

Comment: Edited my answer to give you the correct usage :)

Comment: One more question plz just to make sure I understand you correctly- So in your first sentence you mean that X is USEFUL but heating is more useful (we put only one A before more and let more modify both practical and useful)

Comment: in the second sentence of yours you say that if X is totally USELESS or NOT USEFUL, then we put A before useful

Comment: Dear @user88067, poor K has answered the question three times over by now. Please carefully read what he says. If you still don't understand it, don't ask a fourth time, but *read it again*. And do not, ever, write "plz". It is very rude. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Reg, I thank poorK for answering the ques twice. However, as long as doubts are not cleared, the ans remain incomplete. I see you are here more to make comments, than posting answers. Furthermore, in the internet where abbreviations like faq are used even in formal websites, I believe plz is nothing rude. As long as the other person gets the message, the purpose is served. Don't go by the way how a feeling is communicated, just go by the content & honest inntention of the communication. I guess this would end the argument on this off-topic matter. Thanx (hope u get my message Thank You)

Comment: However, if still someone gets hurt by the word plz, I apologize. All I wanted to say, is to make a request and say Please. Since I find that using Plz offends people, I will avoid using it in future, because I don't want to hurt someone's feeling. Anyways, Thank you for your help, suggestions and answer.